# progress bar is making new line, would like for it to reset to begining

Tags: python

I would like to show one progress bar the resets when its finished. Here is the code. When you run it you can see it makes a new line every time .

```
import time
import sys
toolbar_width = 40
numbers = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for number in numbers:

    for i in xrange(toolbar_width):
                time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
                # update the bar
                sys.stdout.write("-")
                sys.stdout.flush()

    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print a carriage return when you are done:

```
import time
import sys
toolbar_width = 40
numbers = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for number in numbers:
    #print number

    for i in xrange(toolbar_width):
                time.sleep(0.1) # do real work here
                # update the bar
                sys.stdout.write("-")
                sys.stdout.flush()

    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- here!
```

This way, the cursor will go back to the beginning of the line.

However, this will go to the beginning of the line and keep what was there before, as @Kevin comments below. To blank the line you can print a long line with spaces surrounded by `\r`: the first to start printing at the beginning of the given line and the second to put the cursor back in the beginning.

```
sys.stdout.write("\r                       \r")
```

Comment: Good start, but just printing "\r" won't erase the already existing text. So it will appear as though nothing happens after the bar fills up the first time.

Comment: Uhms, true. It looks a bit ugly, but you can also print a "blank" line --> `sys.stdout.write("\r                       \r")`

Comment: Agreed - if you print enough spaces and a second carriage return, it will effectively erase the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sys.stdout.write("\r" + " " * toolbar_width + "\r")
```

instead of

```
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Explain:

- `\r` -- return at the beginning of line
- `" " * toolbar_width`  -- fill the line with space of the size toolbar_width
- `\r`  -- return again at the beginning of line